# How to find the coordinates of the mid point of the sector in a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I have to find the coordinates of the mid point of the sector in the circumference of the circle . Could you please help ?

Let's consider the circle below with
 radius of 10cm with the center as (5,5)
 sector in Grey color is of 30degree.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the midpoint of the arc that makes up the outside edge, or some sort of center of mass or something of the whole sector?

Comment: Yes in the outside edge which is the curved path... actually I need to write the percentage of that pie outside the circumference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every point of the circle is given by the equations

$
x=x_c+r \cos \theta\\
y=y_c+r\sin\theta
$

As I don't know how much is $\alpha$ you must do it by yourself. Suppose $\alpha=40°$. Then we have:

$x=5 +10\cos \left(\alpha+30°/2\right)=5+10\cos 55°\approx 10.74\\
y=5+10\sin \left(\alpha +30°/2\right)=5+10\sin 55°\approx 13.2
$

Hope this helps
$$...$$

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you get the point M when you simply use θ=40+(30/2).         If we need the mid point in Brown sector which is of angle 45°, then x=5+10cos(40+30+45/2) and y=5+10Sin(40+30+45/2) ?

Comment: @iappmaker yes of course. And this for all sectors. I have edited my answer with a new graph

Comment: Just adding a point to help members who are away from maths for long time..  The unit of angle in trigonometry is in radians. radian=angle*3.14/180.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have incorporated your advice in chart section of my app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitcoin.altcoin.portfolio